# java what url value for db driver, using wamp

Tags: java

I have a wamp server and when I run it

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql", name, password);
```

what should be the value of url?

I mean what should be the end point, I think its a driver file, but which file?

isn't mysql.exe?

in the docs is said: a database url of the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname

but what is a database url?, what it should be in wamp for example?

Answer (score 0):

Read the JDBC...

It should be

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName?" + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw"
```

where dbName is your database name, and sqluser, sqluserpw is the username and password, which you should store in those variables. It's your choice whether you send as plain text or whatever.

EDIT: you have to also first load the driver like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Further EDIT: You should put all these, along with your MySQL statements in a function which throws an exception along the lines of try/catch.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test, I've created a database test, but get this error...

Comment: Did you use the driver I say above? Also don't forget to import: java.sql.Connection; java.sql.DriverManager; java.sql.PreparedStatement; java.sql.ResultSet; java.sql.SQLException; java.sql.Statement; java.util.Date;

Comment: Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance(); - I'am using this, I should use exactly the above?, yes I've imported java.sql.*

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver - now I get this